# Hide or Show div based on option selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show or hide the div based on the option selected. When Customer is selected, it should show retCustDetails and when Trade is selected it should show tradeCustDetails.

Please let me know what I'm missing on the codes below.

```
<h2>Place order</h2>
            Your details
            Customer Type: <select id="show" name="customerType" onchange="change()">
                <option value="">Customer Type?</option>
                <option value="ret">Customer</option>
                <option value="trd">Trade</option>
            </select>

            <div id="retCustDetails" class="custDetails">
                Forename <input type="text" name="forename" id="forename" />
                Surname <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" />
            </div>
            <div id="tradeCustDetails" class="custDetails" style="visibility:hidden">
                Company Name <input type="text" name="companyName" id="companyName" />
            </div>
```

JS

```
function change(obj) {

    var selectBox = obj;
    var selected = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
    var retCustDetails = document.getElementById("retCustDetails");
    var tradeCustDetails = document.getElementById("tradeCustDetails");

    if(selected === '1'){
        retCustDetails.style.display = "block";
        tradeCustDetails.style.display = "none";
    }
    else{
        retCustDetails.style.display = "none";
        tradeCustDetails.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were few minor mistakes in your code, I have corrected it to make it work -

```html
<body>
<h2>Place order</h2>
            Your details
            Customer Type: <select id="show" name="customerType" onchange="change(this)">
                <option value="">Customer Type?</option>
                <option value="ret">Customer</option>
                <option value="trd">Trade</option>
            </select>

            <div id="retCustDetails" class="custDetails" style="display:none">
                Forename <input type="text" name="forename" id="forename" />
                Surname <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" />
            </div>
            <div id="tradeCustDetails" class="custDetails" style="display:none">
                Company Name <input type="text" name="companyName" id="companyName" />
            </div>
<script>

function change(obj) {

    var selectBox = obj;
    var selected = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
    var retCustDetails = document.getElementById("retCustDetails");
    var tradeCustDetails = document.getElementById("tradeCustDetails");

    if(selected == 'ret'){
        retCustDetails.style.display = "block";
        tradeCustDetails.style.display = "none";
    }
    else{
        retCustDetails.style.display = "none";
        tradeCustDetails.style.display = "block";
    }
}
</script>
   
   </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `visibility:hidden` in your html but in your `js` your are changing the `display` property.
Change `visibility:hidden` to `display:none`.

Use `this` as `change` funtion's parameter like `onchange="change(this)"`

And JS function change to following.

```
function change(obj) {

    var selectBox = obj.value; 
    var retCustDetails = document.getElementById('retCustDetails');
    var tradeCustDetails = document.getElementById('tradeCustDetails');

    if(selectBox == 'ret'){
       retCustDetails.style.display = "block";
       tradeCustDetails.style.display = "none";
    }
    else{
       retCustDetails.style.display = "none";
       tradeCustDetails.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative method. This too works. Cheers !

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#show').change(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        if( val == 'ret') {
            $('#retCustDetails').show();
            $('#tradeCustDetails').hide();
        } else if(val == 'trd') {
            $('#tradeCustDetails').show();
            $('#retCustDetails').hide();
        } else {
            $('#tradeCustDetails').hide();
            $('#retCustDetails').hide();
        }
    }); 
});
</script>

<h2>Place order</h2>
Your details
Customer Type: <select id="show" name="customerType">
    <option value="">Customer Type?</option>
    <option value="ret">Customer</option>
    <option value="trd">Trade</option>
</select>

<div id="retCustDetails" class="custDetails" style="display:none">
    Forename <input type="text" name="forename" id="forename" />
    Surname <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" />
</div>
<div id="tradeCustDetails" class="custDetails" style="display:none">
    Company Name <input type="text" name="companyName" id="companyName" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

pass the **this** as argument to the *change()* method. Also change the if condition as like below

```
if(selected === 'ret'){
//...
}
```

because you get the selected value, it give either **"ret"** or **"trd"**

Change the **tradeCustDetails** visibility: hidden to display: none
Try this code.

```js
  function change(obj) {
    //alert(obj);
    var selectBox = obj;
    var selected = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
    var retCustDetails = document.getElementById("retCustDetails");
    var tradeCustDetails = document.getElementById("tradeCustDetails");
    if(selected === 'ret'){
        retCustDetails.style.display = "block";
        tradeCustDetails.style.display = "none";
    }
    else{
        retCustDetails.style.display = "none";
        tradeCustDetails.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

```html
<h2>Place order</h2>
            Your details
            Customer Type: <select id="show" name="customerType" onchange="change(this)">
                <option value="">Customer Type?</option>
                <option value="ret">Customer</option>
                <option value="trd">Trade</option>
            </select>

            <div id="retCustDetails" class="custDetails">
                Forename <input type="text" name="forename" id="forename" />
                Surname <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" />
            </div>
            <div id="tradeCustDetails" class="custDetails" style="display:none">
                Company Name <input type="text" name="companyName" id="companyName" />
            </div>
```

Hope this will help you.